# Document.ready is not working but other jquery code is working?

Tags: jquery

I am getting exception in document.ready  as $ is undefined, Why?
 if I removed document .ready function other jquery code working fine . following is my code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () { alert('Hi'); });
        function LoginTypeChanged() {
            if ($('#loginType option:selected').val() === "1") {
                $("#txtUserName").prop('disabled', false);
                $("#txtPassword").prop('disabled', false);
                $("#txtDomain").prop('disabled', false);
            }
            else if ($('#loginType option:selected').val() === "0") {
                $("#txtUserName").val("");
                $("#txtPassword").val("");
                $("#txtDomain").val("");
                $("#txtUserName").prop('disabled', true);
                $("#txtPassword").prop('disabled', true);
                $("#txtDomain").prop('disabled', true);

            }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: If you're getting `$ is undefined` it means you have not included jQuery in the page properly.

Comment: Can you make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) recreating your problem.

Comment: you have to put `<script src="jquery.js"></script>` BEFORE any code that actually uses jquery.

Comment: you are correct. but if I removed ready function then other jquery code is working it means its loaded.

Comment: The rest of the code is not generating an error because it's in a function that is not called. If you call the function `LoginTypeChanged()` you'll also get an error "$ is not defined". As everybody said, include jQuery first :)

Comment: You also appear to be closing the document ready function and then calling the second function after it:  $(document).ready(function () { alert('Hi'); });

Comment: @lharby He's not calling a function. He's just defining it, which generates no error, even if jQuery is not loaded (Then he can add a call to this function in the $(document).ready)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 possible issues:

1. You are missing the **jquery** reference
2. Your script code was added before the **jquery** script.

Comment: thanks ianaya ,  I 've added script in head tag and its working. previously it was at the bottom of html .

Answer (score 0):

you need to add something like this

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```